# What is the mean of " to have " in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Today i find this sentence : '' I'm excited to have you in the class .''

In this sentence , i can not understand what is the mean of 'to have' . Can you clarify and inform  what does it mean as well as how i can use to have in other sentences.

Comment: Did you look up 'have' in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes sir, but i could not understand the meaning of to have in here as well as i faced problem the way of how can i use this sentence .

Answer (score 1):

“to have” implies the meaning of possession. “to have” is infinitive form here.

Your example:  I'm excited to have you in the class .
It means, I am excited that I have you in the class.

Comment: Thank you @Muhammad jahid for clarifying the question.God bless you.